# How to access Request.Properties in ActionExecutingContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

How to access `Request.Properties` in `ActionExecutingContext`?

```
public class UserFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actionContext)
    {
        // Properties is not part of the Request here, so I can't access it
        // Here Request is of type System.Web.HttpRequestBase
        actionContext.HttpContext.Request.Properties.Add("UserData", new UserData());
    }
}
```

I can do it in `ApiController`:

```
public class HomeController : ApiController
{
    public HomeController()
    {
        // Here I can do it (here Request is of type
        // System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage
        this.Request.Properties.Add("UserData", new UserData());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `ApiController` you need use another `ActionFilterAttribute` (located in `System.Web.Http.Controllers` namespace):

```
    using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
    using System.Web.Http.Filters;

    public class UserFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
                    // Properties is part of the Request here, you can access it
                    // actionContext.Request.Properties
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

actionContext.ActionDescriptor.Properties.Add("UserData", new UserData());

Comment: How does this help? you seem to just be adding a random object?